# Functions in disk algebra with summable series coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, several-complex-variables

We know that there are functions $f \in {A}(\mathbb{D}) = C(\overline{\mathbb{D}}) \cap \mathrm{Hol}(\mathbb{D})$ such that $f(z) = \sum_{k\geq0}a_k z^k$ on $\mathbb{D}$ with $a=(a_k)_{k\geq0} \notin \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$. This happens because $\imath \colon \ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \to {A}(\mathbb{D})$ given by $\imath(a) = \sum_{k\geq0} a_kz^k$ cannot be surjective.

Are there any characterisations of $\imath(\ell^1(\mathbb{N}))$? In other words, I have $g \in {A}(\mathbb{D})$; when does the power series of $g$ have summable coefficients?

Also, if $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}^m$, $m\geq 2$, and continuous on its closure, when does $g(z_1,\dots,z_m) = \sum_{h_1,\dots,h_m\geq0} a_{h_1\cdots h_m}z_1^{h_1}\cdots z_m^{h_m}$ with $a \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N}^m)$?

Comment: Characterization in terms of what? I think that having $\sum |a_n| < \infty$ is as simple as it goes; it's fairly easy to construct functions that are continuous on the boundary but with non summable coefficients seen by inspection (eg $\sum \frac {e^{i n\ log n}}{n+1}z^n$ as well as construct such that have summable coefficients but have the unit circle as natural boundary etc (pick your favorite lacunary series with unit circle as natural boundary and integrate it a few times if needed to make summable coefficients)

Comment: @Conrad, characterization in the form "$g$ has summable coefficients if and only if it has a certain property". Of course, "$g$ has summable coefficients" is simple, but useless if it is the conclusion you'd like to get given some $g$. In particular, I'm interested in some property (P) such that the implication "if $g$ has property (P), then $\sum |a_n| < \infty$" holds.

Comment: I get that but afaik there is no simpler property than $\sum |a_k| < \infty$; anyway look up Wiener algebra (that is the name of the algebra of functions with absolutely convergent Fourier series and this is the intersection of $H^{\infty}$ (or $A(D)$ ) with it so maybe you can find something that works for you